# Automating a Jquery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My previous question was taken down as i was too vague so i have decided to throw it back out there in a better format.

So basically i have my javascript slider that works almost perfectly, i have decided to try to make it automatically scroll through images on the slider however, being me i've failed and broke it and now the images don't show at all. I have a jsfiddle of the code which i will link here: http://jsfiddle.net/wDmM7/

This is the javascript which i know is the Problem:

```
    $(document).ready( function($)
{

    timer = window.setInterval("autoSlide()", 1000);
    function autoSlide()"next()".click(); }



    var SliderWrapper = $('.SliderWrapper').find('ul');
    $(SliderWrapper).find('li.active').show();

    window.SliderWrapper = 
    {
        previous: function()
        {
            var current = $( SliderWrapper ).find('li.active');
            var prevElement = $( current ).prev('li');

            if( prevElement.length != 0 )
                {
                    $( current ).removeClass('active').fadeOut(2500);
                    $( prevElement ).addClass('active').fadeIn(2500);
                }

         },
         next: function()
         {
            var current = $( SliderWrapper ).find('li.active');
            var nextElement = $( current ).next('li');

            if(nextElement.length != 0 ) 
                {
                    $( current ).removeClass('active').fadeOut(2500);
                    $( nextElement ).addClass('active').fadeIn(2500);   
                }
            }
    }
});
```

Any Questions i will answer as soon as i can, i only that you be patient as i am a Junior Web Developer and am still learning.

I thank you all in advance.

Comment: you missed one brace, it should be like  `function autoSlide(){"next()".click(); }`

Comment: Open your console, fix errors. SO is not a debugging helpdesk...

Comment: @A.Wolff as i said,  i am a junior developer and i am still learning, i needed a point in the right direction.

Comment: @user3592455 No worries, np. Best advice you can get is for debugging purpose to at least open your console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the `SliderWrapper.next()` function in the timer like this. You can comment out the `autoSlide()`.

*Code:*

```
timer = window.setInterval("window.SliderWrapper.next()", 2000);

//function autoSlide(){"next()".click(); }
```

Comment: That worked, but it only worked for one image, and tips on why that might be?

Answer (score 0):

Line 5: `function autoSlide()"next()".click(); }`

Is not valid javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your line 5 which is invalid javascript code:

```
function autoSlide()"next()".click(); }
```

With new code

```
function autoSlide().next().click();
```